# How to fail Ajax.BeginForm in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Ajax.BeginForm with OnSuccess & OnFailure javascript handlers.

How do fail from my controller so that OnFailure is called?

Yes, I used to call throw new HttpException(404) and it used to work.

But now, I have set a custom error handler that calls Server.ClearError(). Due to this Ajax.BeginForm thinks that no error has occurred.

I am using the error handler given here: [ASP.NET MVC Custom Error Handling Application_Error Global.asax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171035/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-handling-application-error-global-asax)

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to throw an Exception.  HttpException(404) is Not Found, which I don't think counts as an exception for OnFaiulre.  Anything that results in a HTTP 500 should be interpreted as an error by the script.

Comment: I think it is anything above the 2xx range, but regardless, if customerrors is on in web.config, it will never get called.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this, is to set the Response.StatusCode = 500 and append a Header to my response object Response.AppendHeader("MyResponseHeader", "My Message");

In my .js OnFailure handler...

```
function OnFailure(ajaxContext) {
    alert(ajaxContext.status); // 500
    alert(ajaxContext.getResponseHeader("MyResponseHeader"));  // "My Message"
}
```