# Override all GET requests ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

What is the best way to override all GET requests in .NET MVC and pipe them to a single controller's action?

I want only POST requests to go through the standard pipeline, e.g.

```
GET /Eating/Apples -> /GlobalProcessor/Index
POST /Eating/Apples -> /Eating/Apples
```

If .NET filters are your answer, then how would I accomplish that without using RedirectToAction(), as I need to maintain the URL structure. Meaning,

```
GET /Eating/Apples
```

Would be processed by /GlobalProcessor/Index but appear to the client as /Eating/Apples

And if you are wondering why -- it is for a dynamic AJAX processing backend that I'm implementing.

Comment: This is suspiciously sounding like an XY problem to me... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/134199

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I disagree. I'm asking how to override GET and let the rest of the items pass through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a route that matches everything and then have an `IRouteConstraint` that matches when the request method is `GET`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Get", 
"{*path}", 
new {controller = "GlobalProcessor", action = "Index" }, 
new {isGet = new IsGetRequestConstraint()} );
```

With `IsGetRequestConstraint` being:

```
public class IsGetRequestConstraint: IRouteConstraint 
{ 
  public bool Match ( HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection ) 
  { 
    return httpContext.Request.Method == "GET"; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding something like this in your routes config

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "GlobalProcessorThingy",
    "{*url}",
    new { controller = "GlobalProcessor", action = "Index" }
);
```

I tailored an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001081/asp-net-mvc-catch-all-route-and-default-route) SO question