# Error 500 instead of 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I have an asp.net MVC 5 project and I'm trying to throw a 404 error instead of 500.

The errors are

> A public action method 'something' was not found on controller
>   'ProjetX.Controllers.HomeController'

and

> The controller for path '/something' was not found or does not implement
>   IController

I understand why it's an error 500 but I would like to throw a 404. It would be better for SEO.

I can't figure out how to

Here's my code

My ExceptionHandler class for elmah

```
public class HandleCustomError : HandleErrorAttribute
    {

        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            //If the exeption is already handled we do nothing
            if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //Log the exception with Elmah
                Log(filterContext);

                Type exceptionType = filterContext.Exception.GetType();

                //If the exception is while an ajax call
                if (exceptionType == typeof(ExceptionForAjax))
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = filterContext.Exception.Message;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.OnException(filterContext);
                }

            }

            //Make sure that we mark the exception as handled
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }

        private void Log(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            // Retrieve the current HttpContext instance for this request.
            HttpContext httpContext = context.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context;

            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Wrap the exception in an HttpUnhandledException so that ELMAH can capture the original error page.
            Exception exceptionToRaise = new HttpUnhandledException(message: null, innerException: context.Exception);

            // Send the exception to ELMAH (for logging, mailing, filtering, etc.).
            ErrorSignal signal = ErrorSignal.FromContext(httpContext);
            signal.Raise(exceptionToRaise, httpContext);
        }

    }
```

How I add the custom errors

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleCustomError());
        }
```

The routes config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("Robots.txt",
                "robots.txt",
                new { controller = "robot", action = "index" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Localization",
                url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { lang = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}$" }

            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

       routes.MapRoute(
        "NotFound",
        "{*url}",
        new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" }
        );


            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        }
```

My webconfig

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <!-- 2MB-->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097152" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <!-- Set mode to RemoteOnly in production -->
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="/Error/Error500">
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="/Error/Error400" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/Error404" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error/Error500" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="400" path="/Error/Error400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/Error404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/Error500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="Robots-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="/robots.txt" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

I wanted to handle the error in the HandleCustomError class but the problem is that it goes straight to my Error500 action in the error controller.

What's weird is that the error is still logged in elmah.

It doesn't hit any breakpoint inside the HandleCustomError class, how can the error be logged?

Thank you

Comment: You can't return a 404 in the Error500 action in the error controller?

Comment: How do I know if it's a real 500 error or those 2 specific errors in the error controller?

Comment: What two specific errors?

Comment: Those at the top of my question

Comment: I see 404 and 500.  You say you want to replace 500 with 404.  So...?

Comment: A public action method 'something' was not found on controller 'ProjetX.Controllers.HomeController' throws a 500 but I would prefer a 404

Comment: Swap it with 404 in the Error500 action in the error controller.

Comment: If a server-side method is not implemented, why throw a client-side error?

Comment: That would replace all error 500 for a 404

Comment: @HimBromBeere this error happens when someone types a wrong url. it should be a 404. no?

Comment: Do you have a catchall route in your routing configuration?

Comment: So you provide the name of the function to be called within the url, right? And this function may or may not be implementing leading to the mentioned error?

Comment: What you really need to do is fix the problem that's causing the 500 error.

Comment: I tried ``routes.MapRoute(
            "NotFound",
            "{*url}",
            new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" }
            );`` but it didn't change anything

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, mvc tries to find a controller that match the url.

Comment: Which route is it actually hitting?

Comment: I'm not sure how to verify that. It goes straight to the error 500 and it tells me theres no controller that match the request

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx/

Comment: This also looks helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001081/asp-net-mvc-catch-all-route-and-default-route

Comment: Thank you Robert, the second link works like a charm. You can write this as an answer. I will add my code also

Comment: @RobertHarvey Don't forget to write your answer to get your points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the final code that works

I had to add 2 functions to generate a regex with all the name of my controllers and actions

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Localization",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { lang = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}$", controller = GetAllControllersAsRegex(), action = GetAllActionsAsRegex }

        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { controller = GetAllControllersAsRegex(), action = GetAllActionsAsRegex() }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        "NotFound",
        "{*url}",
        new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" }
        );

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
    private static string GetAllControllersAsRegex() 
    { 
        var controllers = typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller))); 

        var controllerNames = controllers
            .Select(c => c.Name.Replace("Controller", "")); 

        return string.Format("({0})", string.Join("|", controllerNames)); 
    }
    private static string GetAllActionsAsRegex()
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        var actions = asm.GetTypes()
                        .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type)) //filter controllers
                        .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
                        .Where(method => method.IsPublic && !method.IsDefined(typeof(NonActionAttribute)))
                        .Select(x=>x.Name);

        return string.Format("({0})", string.Join("|", actions)); 
    }
}
```

**See Also**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668252

Comment: Could you write your comment about the catch-all route as an answer, I will give you the points plz

Comment: This doesn't look like the catchall route played much of a part in the solution.

Comment: Your second link about the constraints helped