# Possible to create catch all route for a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

For a specific controller, is it possible to route any action that does not exist to the index?

For example if I have

```
fashionController/
fashionController/shoes/
fashionController/bags/
fashionController/otherStuff/
```

I want to be able to only setup the Index view & action and that anything else will just use the Index automatically without having to create separate views/actions for anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

There is no requirement that controller or action name are part of Url. For example you can route all "fashion/*" to the same action with following route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "AllToIndex",
            "fashion/{argument1}",
            new { controller = "fashion", action = "Index", argument1 = "" }
        );
```

Note that routes matched in order they are added, so if you register this route after default `"{controller}/{action}"` one it will never be matched. Generally more specific routes should go before more generic once and last should be optional ["cath'em all"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001081/asp-net-mvc-catch-all-route-and-default-route) one with `"{*path}"` math.

Comment: I think you mean `"{*path}"` for the catch-all route.

Comment: @Eilon indeed. Thanks for pointing it out. Also added link to question that describes it in more details.

Comment: ok wow that works really well, however is it possible to mix it, so if the action/view exists for the controller it will go there, otherwise it will default to the catchall Index?

Comment: @PmbDenton I personally would explicitly specify routes I want to send to actions (either separately or with constraint on single route). There are probably other ways to do so - there are plenty different questions/articles on ASP.Net MVC routing if basic matching stops working for your needs. I.e. there is specific tag on SO for this kind of questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-routing