# ASP.NET-MVC How to return correct response code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Lets take a look at simple example:

Route config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Test",
         url: "{action}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Api" }
    );
}
```

Controller

```
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
       return Content("Test");
    }
}
```

If we call this with following url:
    www.mysite.com/test
we get the expected result, namely the string "Test".

But, if we try to access somenonexisting http endpoint like

```
www.mysite.com/noneexisting
```

We get server 500 response, indicating internal server error. This url should result in response code 404, indicating nonexistent resource.
This is so wrong. It is misleading for an api consumer. Why is this so? How to configure IIS, MVC to return correct response codes?

Complete server response is:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Content-Type: text/html Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/8.0 Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 12:38:39 GMT Content-Length:
>   75
>
> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

For additional info I include my web.config. It is almost stock as VS made it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <!-- no authentication at all -->
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/> <!-- this will allow access to everyone to register.aspx -->
        </authorization>

        <pages>
            <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
        <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <!--
                If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
                you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
                change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
                of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
            -->
        <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
        <staticContent>
            <!-- font files -->
            <remove fileExtension=".eot"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="font/svg" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Let's rephrase the question. Your request is being mapped to *something*. What could it be? No other routes? Do you still have the default route? Could you be making requests of an action method on your Home Controller. Any other possibilities?

Comment: No other pissibilietis. This is everything. The problem is that MVC returns 500 response but it should return 404, as a resource (endpoint) does not exist.

Comment: There must be routes you're not showing in your `RegisterRoutes`

Comment: @jumpingcode No, this is it.

Comment: Very strange. So, just to confirm, you only have this web api project on the domain? Where is request coming from? You cannot be serving a view from your solution if your explanation holds.

Comment: @f470071 Having looked at your previous questions, it's clear you are struggling with how to use `ApiController`. Unless you are willing to show your `RegisterRoutes` in full, we won't be able to help you. I'm 100% certain your issue lies there, but you believe it is a bug with MVC that no-one else is experiencing.

Comment: Where is request coming from? You cannot be serving a view from your solution if your explanation holds.

Comment: @Dave Request is coming form the wide world of the internet. And I am not serving View. The above method Test actually returns content with string "test" as it should. Method test is not a problem.

Comment: Interesting. You seem to be getting a page response. In all likelihood, you are getting a page response of 404. Try turning custom error off in your `web.config`.

Comment: @Dave I have no custom errors in my web.config. I have included web.config althouh it is big. I came to the same idea as you.

Comment: And yet another thing. On hosting on IIS 8.0 this has a problem I described. On IIS express on my local desktop this returns 404. I am lost. I am so so sorry I did not start this in PHP.

Comment: @dave I added <customErrors mode="Off" /> in </system.web> still error 500. I have add http://localhost/nakupnik/api/testc also to my local IIS express config and this still returns 404 as it should.

Comment: I was wondering if it would add the error to your IIS environment too. But, I think this is the answer: ` <!-- Override it for paths starting with api (your WebAPI) -->
  <location path="api">
     <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
     </system.web>
  </location>`

Comment: If I could just only somehow see what is wrong, At the moment all I am doing are pure guesses blindly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79545/discussion-on-question-by-f470071-asp-net-mvc-how-to-return-correct-response-cod).

Comment: I cannot use chat. And I think I will flagthis question for deleting. Dave has put great effort into, but all this long thread of comments will serve no purpose for future readers.

Comment: click on the chat link. BTW, @f470071, I just realized, you are mapping a MVC routes, not Web API routes.
Try this: `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute`

Comment: @dave he is routing alright. His controller is an mvc controller not an api one even though he named it that way...check inherited type.

Comment: Would downvoter care to comment. Yet another one of those not capable of grasping the problem.