# Redirect to a different MVC controller when supplying an empty URL parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Question Background:**

I have a URL  that contains a parameter called `pageNo` that is sent to a controller called `Events` with a method called `FutureEvents` that is being called. This is used with pagination to determine the page number of a view that needs to be shown. This is the URL:

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/Events/FutureEvents?pageNo=1
```

**The Issue:**

If the user manually types the URL and **doesn't** supply the page number parameter in the URL, for example:

```
http://localhost:51025/Events/FutureEvents
```

then an ASP error shows with the message:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'pageNo' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult FutureEvents(Int32)'

This makes sense as the parameter is null. What I want to do is redirect the user to another controller (in this case my `Home` Controller and `Index` method) when the user tries to call the `FutureEvents` controller and `Events` method with an empty `pageNo` parameter.

This is my current route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The `Home` Controller with its Index method - this is what I want to redirect to.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

The `FutureEvents` Controller with the `Events` method:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult FutureEvents(int pageNo)
 {
     //code
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass the parameter in function we need put then or set a initial value.

int pageNo = 0 or int? pageNo

```
   [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult FutureEvents(int pageNo = 0)
     {
         //code
     }
```

all others functions without parameters open normally.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define two routes, one with parameter (not optional) and one without parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute( // because id is required, route will be skipped
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Events", action = "FutureEvents"}
    );

routes.MapRoute( // catch all routes that doesn't match the others.
        name: "CatchAll",
        url: "{*everything}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
```

You can see this answer for [more informations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001081/asp-net-mvc-catch-all-route-and-default-route).

Answer (score 0):

or if you want use the session to pass the page number
in this way their is no worry about editing the page number by the user

Session["Pagenumber"]=value;

//redirect to an action