# Is there a way to discriminate a specific System.Web.HttpException?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, .net-4.6.1, httpexception

I've some "bad boys" users which call my website using controller that doesn't exist.
Such as `www.myapp.com/.svn/`, or `www.myapp.com/wp-admin/`.

The app basically throw a `System.Web.HttpException`, which this `ExceptionMessage`: *The controller for path '...' was not found or does not implement IController.*

Is there a way to exactly catch this "sub" `System.Web.HttpException` in a robust way? (not comparing the string of `ExceptionMessage`, of course).

Any sub InnerException type and/or some "code" which indicate that exact exception?

Comment: There are no properties on HttpException that can help you. You'll either have to figure out how to intercept the request before it becomes an exception or you're back to parsing the message.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen and how can I intercept it? For example, to check if the requested controller exist?

Comment: I think you need a simple configuration inside *web.config* file. Please read the page https://stackify.com/aspnet-mvc-error-handling/ carefully.

Comment: @AmirhosseinMehrvarzi this works for generic http message (i.e. 400, 401, and so on). In this case, I Need to route if controller doesn't exist

Comment: What do you think about this topic: [How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc/620559#620559)

Answer (score 3):

You might create a custom `IControllerFactory`, e.g. by deriving from [`DefaultControllerFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Its [`GetControllerInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory.getcontrollerinstance?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method will be called with a `null` value for the `controllerType` argument, when no matching controller could be resolved.
At this point, you are ahead of the `Exception`.

```
IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
```

Here you decide how to handle the request, like e.g. logging and/or handling the request by a specific controller.

The example below shows how the `ErrorController` is being used as fallback, executing its `Index` action method.

```
class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            var routeData = requestContext.RouteData;
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
            controllerType = typeof(ErrorController);
        }

        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
}
```

A custom controller factory gets installed from within e.g. `Application_Start` in `Global.asax.cs` using:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new CustomControllerFactory());
```

---

Note that this doesn't guard you from a related exception in case the contoller does exist, but the action doesn't.

E.g. given a `HomeController` without an `Ufo` action method, the url `www.myapp.com/home/ufo` results in an `Exception` `"A public action method 'ufo' was not found on controller '...HomeController"`.

A simple solution to handle such scenario is by overriding [`HandleUnknownAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.handleunknownaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) in a custom base controller of which all your controllers inherit.

The example below shows how a shared `Error` view (`Shared\Error.cshtml`) gets executed.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
    {
        View("Error").ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem as you have stated seems like a `routing` problem.

Have you tried a `catch all` route?... That is a route that is executed when no other route matches the request's path. The `catch all` route is defined last and seems like:

```cs
// Specific routes here...

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Catch-All",
    "{*controller}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

I tested with .NET Core MVC

```cs
// This is how it is configured in .NET Core MMVC
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "catch-all",
            pattern: "{*controller}",
            defaults: new { controller="Home", action="Index" });
});
```

[image]

I think that managing the excepion, as sugested in previous answers, is a good practice, but does not solve the routing problem you are facing.

You might want to take a look to this discussion regarding similiar problem with ASP.NET MVC:
[ASP.NET MVC - Catch All Route And Default Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001081/asp-net-mvc-catch-all-route-and-default-route)

Comment: The code above doesn't load Home/Index if i request a random path :( (such as /wp-admin). Are you saying this?

Comment: Updated my answer, I am testing with .NET Core (no ASP.NET MVC 4.6 available) and was able to catch-all non matching urls. Also included a link with a discussion regarding the same issue.

Comment: Instead of routing to `/home/index` you maight redirect to a 404 page.

Comment: tried, but doesn't work on .NET 4.6.1. It trigger protected void Application_Error() method, that's all.

Answer (score -1):

Like @Amirhossein [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743997/amirhossein-mehrvarzi), since you are using .net 4.6 framework you can have a global exception catch inside the
`Global.asax` file something like:

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
        var ex = Server.GetLastError();

        Debug.WriteLine(ex);

        var httpEx = ex as HttpException;
        var statusCode = httpEx?.GetHttpCode() ?? 500;

        Server.ClearError();
        ...
  }
```

or you can address this issue via IIS (since I presume you host your application on IIS) by adding a mapping rule (which in turn can be done in the web.config) or by adding a filter, or even a firewall rule (since by my account those kind of probing scans are not worth to be logged in your application - I believe they should be handled on another level)