# MVC Exception Log into log file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

- When `customErrors mode ="Off"`, it shows custom error page and save exception in the log file.
- When `customErrors mode ="On"`, it shows custom error page but does not create any log file.

What is the issue?

**Code:**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
     Exception filterContext = Server.GetLastError();
                //Server.ClearError();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder
                    .AppendLine("start")
                    .AppendLine(DateTime.Now.ToString()+filterContext.Source)
    SendMail("****@gmail.com", "Error Details", builder.ToString());
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Error_" + 
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".log");
        using (StreamWriter writer = System.IO.File.AppendText(filePath))
        {
            writer.Write(builder.ToString());
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
```

and my custom error page

```
 public ActionResult NotFound()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public ActionResult Error()
            {
                return View();
            }
```

how to store log into text file

Comment: Do I missing something here but there is no code that saves to file and you expect log to be in file.

Comment: string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Error_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".log");
            using (StreamWriter writer = System.IO.File.AppendText(filePath))
            {
                writer.Write(builder.ToString());
                writer.Flush();
            }

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to utilize a logging component such as NLog for this purpose.  Rather than rolling your own logic, utilize something that's already been well developed and tested.  Available in NuGet.  [https://nlog-project.org/](https://nlog-project.org/)

Comment: Try to use 'log4net' instead rolling out your own logic. Why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I will second the previous two comments.  They give you additional features for managing the lifetime of logs and also sending logs to a central location.  The security group usually requires this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log Application Errors when customErros is set to On?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290676/how-to-log-application-errors-when-customerros-is-set-to-on)