# Error.aspx /HandleError

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am doing MVC 2 
I have given HandleError attribute to all of my controller class.
I have 

In my web.config
I also have Error.aspx in my shared folder of views.
Still on an exception in controller, The Error.aspx is not rendered

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171035/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-handling-application-error-global-asax).

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 2 project using the default template
2. `throw new Exception();` inside the Index action of the `HomeController`.
3. Add in web.config: `<customErrors mode="On" />`
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> to run the project
5. The `Error.aspx` page is shown.

Comment: instead of 'throw new Exception();'  try                                                                    'throw new HttpException(401,"wont work");' that wont work

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions about this on StackOverflow because this is a tricky one with a lot of gotchas if you're not careful.  From the sound of it, you need to set the HTTP Response to `OK`, otherwise the server will still render a generic 500 Error page because it still thinks the exception was not handled properly.

To do this, in your error view, add the following code:

`@{
 Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
 }`

Let us know if this works for you!

Edit: You also need to make sure that you have `<customErrors mode="On"/>` in the `<System.Web>` section of the web.config file at the root of your website.