# Global Error handling using PartialView in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, try-catch

I have look at one of the perfect article on [Exception handling in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine#What%E2%80%99sthebestpractice) and want to implement a method as on Method 6 in this article in order to reuse the same error page for all of other modal dialogs on error and exception situations. On the other hand, as I use popup window, I need to render a `PartialView` in my modal dialog instead of redirecting the page. Is it possible to do this?

**AJAX call:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Person")',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: formdata,

    success: function (response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        if (response.success) {
            //display operation result
        }
        else {
            /* At this stage I need to render the Error view as partial without 
            redirecting to Error page on error. The problem at here not directly 
            related to rendering partialview. I need to render the global Error 
            page and reuse it for every error occured on my modal dialog */
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/Error.cshtml", Model)
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(int id)
{
    try
    {
        //code omitted for brevity
    }
    catch (Exception  ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Operation failed." });
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `@Html.Partial()` - that is server side code and is evaluated before its sent to the browser. One option would be to return the partial as JSON - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730777/mvc-return-partial-view-as-json) for an example. Another option would be make a 2nd ajax call in the `else` block to a method that returns your partial

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do you meant to change the Redirect section as **return Json(new { error = true, message = RenderViewToString(PartialView("Error", model))});** in order to render the error page? But I am not sure how to change the Home/Error page in this article given in the question. For example what if I want to create the error page as _Error in Shared folder?

Comment: No, your making an ajax call and ajax calls cannot redirect.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no experience with error handling except from basic try-catch methods. So, could you please have a look at the article and then post the modified Controller method that I should use? Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Any idea please?