# HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAjaxRequest() error in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAjaxRequest()
```

condition to check for an ajax request in global.asax in Application_Error method but I get the below error:

> 'System.Web.HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for
>   'IsAjaxRequest' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.AjaxRequestExtensions.IsAjaxRequest(System.Web.HttpRequestBase)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Below is the code:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

        string ErrorMessage = "";
        ErrorMessage = "Application Level Error";


        logger.Error(ErrorMessage, exception);

        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) //if its an ajax do not redirect
        {
            return;
        }
    else
    {
      Server.ClearError();
      this.Response.RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "Home", action = "Error" });
    }
  }
```

Comment: modified the question to add the code.

Comment: Try `new HttpRequestWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request).IsAjaxRequest()` `IsAjaxRequest()` takes an HttpRequestBase which is different from an HttpRequest (and not related, so it's a bit confusing). I think the wrapper will fix your problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Guess it worked... Posting as the answer.

Try

```
new HttpRequestWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request).IsAjaxRequest()
```

`IsAjaxRequest()` takes an `HttpRequestBase` which is different from an `HttpRequest` (and not related, so it's a bit confusing). I think the wrapper will fix your problem.

Comment: Note that `HttpRequestWrapper` is in the `System.Web` namespace but `IsAjaxRequest()` is an extension method contained in the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly, so you will need to include both in your namespace references

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I resorted to using a static method (I was in an IRouteConstraint Implementation)

`bool isAjax = AjaxRequestExtensions.IsAjaxRequest(httpContext.Request);`

For this to work, don't forget to `include System.Web.Mvc` if you don't have it already.