# Handling exceptions from action filters and orchard framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, orchardcms

Overriding ErrorPage.cshtml allows you to create custom error page for exceptons thrown from controllers, is there a way to handle exceptions thrown from filters? For example I would like to have custom page for anti forgery exceptions.

Comment: Was my answer helpul? If so, accept it so others can use it as well. If it wasn't, did you find a different solution to your problem?

Comment: sorry, but it was not helpful. Your answer is like answer for totally different question. You are talking about error logging system ELMAH, which by the way we also use, which is not a solution to "create custom error page" problem. Also I would like to hear about orchard specific solutions (not necessary).  Moreover the problem lies with filters, everything is working awesome for controllers. I would like to get some info about serving custom page for exception from filter. Including third-party filters from framework (orchard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize exception filters. Just create your own `FilterProvider` and have it implement `IExceptionFilter`. Put all custom logic inside `OnException(filterContext)` method.

Take a look at eg. current implementation of `Orchard.Security.SecurityFilter` to have an idea.

Comment: Expanding FilterProvider was a key, ty

Answer (score 1):

**Exception filters** are available to handle unhandled exceptions thrown during the execution of the ASP.NET MVC pipeline.

Filtering in ASP.NET MVC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [ELMAH](https://elmah.github.io/) for system wide error handling.

For the custom page on forgery you could always try and manipulate the Request from within the action filter.

For custom handling of an error message or exception type look at: [ASP.NET MVC Custom Error Handling Application_Error Global.asax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171035/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-handling-application-error-global-asax)