# ASP.Net MVC 404 File Not Found custom page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Sorry, if question is not clear, but I need "file not found" custom page, not "Page not found". If you type at the end of url .html - it do not will go thru Routes.

I have route which catch all routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", url = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { Domain = new DomainsConstraint() }
        );
```

But how can I make custom page for file not found? If at the and of url I add for example .html - It will show me 404 file not found

Comment: What exactly are you looking for ? do you want to redirect to html page from your controller's action method ? or you want to check if such action method or controller is exist or not ?

Comment: If i have url like myUrl.com/home.html - it will show me file not found. I need just replace this page to custom

Answer (score 1):

Simply set error configuration in web.config file

**Web.config**

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
          <error redirect="~/Controller/Error" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Error(){
   var result = new FilePathResult("~/404.html", "text/html");
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "404-PageNotFound",
    "{*url}",
    new { controller = "StaticContent", action = "PageNotFound" }
    );
```

You can create your own custom error page :

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error redirect="~/StaticContent/PageNotFound" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>

public class StaticContent : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    public ViewResult PageNotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;  //you may want to set this to 200
        return View("PageNotFound");
    }
}
```

Comment: It will catch page not found, but not the file not found

Comment: you can try it: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shay/2009/03/06/real-world-error-hadnling-in-aspnet-mvc-rc2/

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it from Global.asax file.
You can get perfect solution from this answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1171805)