# HTTP 500 errors after publishing MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

I am currently developing a MVC 5 web project using AdminLTE template. When I debug on Visual Studio, there is no problem but if I publish the project and test on my local IIS server, it gives HTTP 500 error.

I checked the all controllers and views and found somethings. On one view I used mysql connection and there is no problem there. Page is working properly, but sql server used pages are not working. Also I used SQL server model on login page. It also works well. Just SQL server connections doesn't work.

I am using SQL Server Express on my machine,
remote mysql,
.NET Framework 4.6.1,
AdminLTE template,
latest IIS server.

I also tried on windows server 2012 r2 standard with SQL Server 2008 r2. I configured web.config but still getting the same errors.

[image: sql used view]

[image: mysql used view]

Comment: Log the exception details (stack trace/inner exception) and see why it is crashing

Comment: Do you have any logging implemented in your application?

Comment: there is no logging implementation. Can you share a link about how to do it?

Comment: check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171035/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-handling-application-error-global-asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171035/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-handling-application-error-global-asax) for how to handle errors in your MVC app

Comment: see this thread and modify web.config as written there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. I solved to problem. I will explain it step by step.

1. I added [log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/) package to solution by NuGet
2. Configured it by the following [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/jhallal/configure-log4net-logging-framework-for-mvc)
3. Checked the log file and saw following error : *Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\user'.*
4. Then I solved that problem according to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0)

Now the project works perfect, thanks.