# IIS 8.5 fails serving ASP.Net MVC pages after app pool recycle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8

We have hit a strange issue which I cannot find any reference to while searching the web.

We have a small number of ASP.Net MVC based apps on a web server which fail after their app pools have recycled.

The default/home returns a blank page, and if you try to go to other pages you get a 404. IIS still serves static content such as css or js if you specifically go to them.

Nothing is recorded in the Win or IIS logs as errors or warnings, nothing stands out.

We can resolve the issue by either redeploying the app or deleting the sites compiled files in the Temp ASP.Net folder, forcing a recompile. But obviously once app pool recycles again it breaks.

The only thing that's changed on the box is a installing .Net Framework 4.7.2 along with a few Win Updates.

However dev versions of the same app or on another box which work fine and that's also been updated to 4.7.2 etc.

How can I solve this?

Comment: hi there. i've not experienced this before but is this of any help? hashtag longshot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079387/mvc-routes-lost-after-app-pool-recycle-updated-title-3-3-14

Comment: A hang dump of the new worker process when "the default/home returns a blank page" should help tell what can be the cause. You should not expect any log file helps. Most likely your web app locks up some resources, so two copies of the web app cannot coexist (but that's mandate during IIS pool recycle).

Comment: Hi @LexLi thanks for your response. 

How do you go about setting up a specific hang dump for the IIS worker.

Didn't even know you could do that.

Should mention I'm not 100% sure anything is 'crashing' at least in the traditional sense, so would this pick up any information?

Comment: Usually you need a senior developer on your side to help, or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to learn from Microsoft.