# .Net MVC 4 Blank Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to deploy the default empty internet application template from .Net MVC 4, my app gives the same problem so figured start with the simplest app I could.

The server is 2008 R2 running .Net 4 (app has been changed to 4 from 4.5).  I have other sites running on that machine with .Net 4 and MVC 3 but the MVC 4 app just brings up a blank page.  I have confirmed HttpRedirection and HttpErrors are installed (and the MVC 3 apps run fine).

I have tried the solution from Michel van Engelen here [I am getting a blank page while deploying MVC application on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557730/i-am-getting-blank-page-while-deploying-mvc-application-on-iis) and confirmed it works on my machine but still a blank page.

Comment: How are you deploying the site right now?

Comment: I am publishing to the file system then copying over to the server.  Same process as the MVC 3 sites.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding ELMAH to try get info on the exception that was causing the problem and the site started working, I am not sure what changes to the web.config to install ELMAH resulted in the site starting but did the same thing to my other original app and all is now fine.