# MVC Debugging displaying blank page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, windows-server-2012-r2

I recently received a new computer for work. I installed VS2017 along with all of the other requirements.

When I run my web app, I can't get it to display anything but a blank page. Even the source code is empty. I am using IIS Express on a Windows 2012R2 server.

[image]

This is pretty much an identical setup as my previous computer. Everything works as intended on my old computer.

When I step through the Logon class, I do not get any noticeable errors.

I have tried changing the port to the IIS Express instance and that didn't change anything. I was hoping there was a conflict somewhere. I have also restarted visual studio.

I'm not even sure where to troubleshoot this since everything looks to be in place and I'm not seeing any errors.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557730/i-am-getting-a-blank-page-while-deploying-mvc-application-on-iis) help?

Comment: I'm going to check my mvc version and see if that is the issue. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @alex That was it! I had to install the right version of mvc! tyvm!