# Blank ASP.NET Webpage for the application deployed on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an *asp.net application deployed on IIS Server* located at 10.0.0.74, when
i tried to access it with chrome browser i get an **empty or blank webpage.**
However if my colleague tries to access it from his computer he get normal webpage with content on it.
It seems really weird to me what might be the problem.
The screen shot below is what the page looks like.
I would appreciate any help
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it not there on the right by the scroll bar?

Comment: It looks like you've got some add-ons/extensions installed that your colleague may not.

Comment: The right scroll bar is part of the page, in fact it is the only part of the page that is being displayed.

Comment: Did you look for JavaScript errors in your console? Did you make sure your browser hasn't cached any old files?

Comment: In the console i see a bunch of 404 error.

Comment: Okay...so why are you getting 404's? Are they requesting resources at the right location? Are they requesting wrong resources? Does your colleague have a cached version of those resources but they don't exist anymore? There's quite a bit of investigating you've got to do.

Comment: You should host those resources locally.  You're linking to external resources... (cdns?)  That opens up security risks.  What may be causing this is partial http/partial https (for linked stuff?)  Some browsers block mixed content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the plugins in "Content" folder were not included in the projects.
I included all the files shown in the image below.

I apologize for wasting your time, i should have checked the console before!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not enough to go on, assuming ASP MVC 5 on IIS here are some suggestions.

**On your server**

[image: IIS Server Roles to Solve ASP MVC blank page 404 403 503 errors]

## Check the following

1. Is the physical path in IIS correct - actually point to your code?
2. Do you have any rewrite rules in your `web.config` that could be redirecting?
3. Did you set up the bindings correctly?
4. Are you hitting the site under https / http?
5. Checked "Turn windows features on/off" and see if ASP.NET 4.8 installed
6. Did you setup the HTTP Redirection and HTTP Errors
7. See how you are setting up error handling setup in your `global.asax`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/633818/6085193) and disable it

Goto your Control panel > Programs and features > Turn Windows features on or off and  under "`World Wide Web Services`" / components:

- Common HTTP features:
- Default document
- Directory browsing
- HTTP Errors
- HTTP Redirection
- Static Content
- Security
- Basic authentication
- Request filtering
- URL Authorization
- Windows authentication